# What is the difference between Varchar and String in sqlalchemy's data type?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqldatatypes

I used to use **Varchar** to text string of dynamical string length. Recently I saw people also use **String** with length to define it.

What is the difference between them? Which one is better to use?

Answer (score 11):

From what I know,

- Use **varchar** if you want to have a *length constraint*
- Use **string** if you *don't want to restrict the length of the text*

> The length field is usually required when the String type is used
> within a CREATE TABLE statement, as **VARCHAR requires a length** on most
> databases
>
> Parameters
>
> **length - optional**, a length for the column for use in DDL and CAST expressions.
> **May be safely omitted** if no CREATE TABLE will be issued. Certain
> databases may require a length for use in DDL, and will raise an
> exception when the CREATE TABLE DDL is issued if a **VARCHAR with no
> length is included**. Whether the value is interpreted as bytes or
> characters is database specific.
>
> SQLAlchemy Docs

Comment: But String also takes length constraints like Varchar does. When shall we use String and when shall we use Varchar?

Comment: @ichbinblau yes but as highlighted above, length is an *optional* parameter for `String` and may be safely omitted

Comment: @ichbinblau does that answer your question??

Answer (score 4):

`String` is more portable, because it is a generic SQLAlchemy type.

For most backends, a `String` column definition in the Python layer will be mapped to backend's `VARCHAR` type, but if the target backend uses some other type then that type will be used.

Thus

```
col = Column(String(1))
```

will work on any RDBMS

but

```
col = Column(VARCHAR(1))
```

will only work on RDBMS that provide an actual `VARCHAR` type.

See the documentation for [The Type Hierarchy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#module-sqlalchemy.types) for more discussion.